# imenu doesn't work on indented C++ code

Tags: imenu

While imenu works very well in most environments, I am having issues when using it in C++ files where functions are not defined flush left.

(Update:)
Steps to reproduce the issue (thanks to Drew's comment below).

- Start `emacs -Q`
- Load the file below.
- Do `M-x imenu`
- I get the error message: "No items suitable for an index found in this buffer".
- If the two functions are not indented (the lines starting with "int"), I instead get the prompt "Index item: ", as expected.

Test file:

```
namespace this_breaks_imenu
{
   int other_function( int argc, char** argv )
   {
     float b;
     return 0;
   }

  int main( int argc, char** argv )
  {
    float a;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

If the code is indented like that (with a couple of extra spaces along the left margin), doing `S-down-mouse-3` which is bound to `(imenu INDEX-ITEM)` gives me "No kbd macro has been defined". The same file without the spaces to the left works fine.

Why is this, and is there any way of working around it, other than changing the indentation of the files (which will not be appreciated by my collaborators)?

Comment: just curious, why would you want extra spaces along the left margin ? Is it just as aesthetic thing ?

Comment: Usually, it is because the functions are within a namespace{} scope, which makes them indented like this.

Comment: I just tested this code in my emacs and `imenu` works for me (I have not added any config for c/c++ modes). I'm pretty sure indentation does not matter for `imenu`

Comment: Do you see the same thing when starting Emacs with no init file (`emacs -Q`)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, please provide a step-by-step recipe to repro (starting from `emacs -Q).

Comment: Yes I do. I have updated the question.

Comment: The regexps in `cc-imenu-c++-generic-expression` are each anchored to the beginning of a word at the start of a line, but don't match indented lines.

Comment: Aha! That's interesting. Now I only need to find the way to properly `setq` that variable. My initial attempts of putting `(setq cc-imenu-c++-generic-expression ((nil "^\\<` etc into .emacs just gives my "invalid function" error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied over the definition of the variable `cc-imenu-c++-generic-expression` and patched the regular expressions that included `^` to `^[ \t]*`. Eval the `setq` (maybe put it in your `init.el`, then open the test file.

```
 (setq cc-imenu-c++-generic-expression
 `(
 ;; Try to match ::operator definitions first. Otherwise `X::operator new ()'
 ;; will be incorrectly recognized as function `new ()' because the regexps
 ;; work by backtracking from the end of the definition.
 (nil
  ,(concat
    "^\\<.*"
    "[^" c-alnum "_:<>~]"                  ; match any non-identifier char
                       ; (note: this can be `\n')
    "\\("
       "\\([" c-alnum "_:<>~]*::\\)?"      ; match an operator
       "operator\\>[ \t]*"
       "\\(()\\|[^(]*\\)"                  ; special case for `()' operator
    "\\)"

    "[ \t]*([^)]*)[ \t]*[^ \t;]"           ; followed by ws, arg list,
                       ; require something other than
                       ; a `;' after the (...) to
                       ; avoid prototypes.  Can't
                       ; catch cases with () inside
                       ; the parentheses surrounding
                       ; the parameters.  e.g.:
                       ; `int foo(int a=bar()) {...}'
    ) 1)
 ;; Special case to match a line like `main() {}'
 ;; e.g. no return type, not even on the previous line.
 (nil
  ,(concat
    "^[ \t]*"
    "\\([" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_:<>~]*\\)" ; match function name
    "[ \t]*("                 ; see above, BUT
    "[ \t]*\\([^ \t(*][^)]*\\)?)"          ; the arg list must not start
    "[ \t]*[^ \t;(]"                       ; with an asterisk or parentheses
    ) 1)
 ;; General function name regexp
 (nil
  ,(concat
    "^[ \t]*\\<"                                 ; line MUST start with word char
    ;; \n added to prevent overflow in regexp matcher.
    ;; http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-pretest-bug/2007-02/msg00021.html
    "[^()\n]*"                             ; no parentheses before
    "[^" c-alnum "_:<>~]"                  ; match any non-identifier char
    "\\([" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_:<>~]*\\)" ; match function name
    "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*("        ; see above, BUT the arg list
    "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*"         ; must not start
    "\\([^ \t\n(*]"               ; with an asterisk or parentheses
    "[^()]*\\(([^()]*)[^()]*\\)*"         ; Maybe function pointer arguments
    "\\)?)"
    "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*[^ \t\n;(]"
    ) 1)
 ;; Special case for definitions using phony prototype macros like:
 ;; `int main _PROTO( (int argc,char *argv[]) )'.
 ;; This case is only included if cc-imenu-c-prototype-macro-regexp is set.
 ;; Only supported in c-code, so no `:<>~' chars in function name!
 ,@(if cc-imenu-c-prototype-macro-regexp
     `((nil
          ,(concat
        "^[ \t]*\\<.*"                   ; line MUST start with word char
        "[^" c-alnum "_]"          ; match any non-identifier char
        "\\([" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_]*\\)" ; match function name
        "[ \t]*"                   ; whitespace before macro name
        cc-imenu-c-prototype-macro-regexp
        "[ \t]*("                  ; ws followed by first paren.
        "[ \t]*([^)]*)[ \t]*)[ \t]*[^ \t;]" ; see above
        ) 1)))
 ;; Class definitions
 ("Class"
  ,(concat
      "^[ \t]*"                                  ; beginning of line is required
      "\\(template[ \t]*<[^>]+>[ \t]*\\)?" ; there may be a `template <...>'
      "\\(class\\|struct\\)[ \t]+"
      "\\("                                ; the string we want to get
      "[" c-alnum "_]+"                    ; class name
      "\\(<[^>]+>\\)?"                     ; possibly explicitly specialized
      "\\)"
      "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*[:{]"
      ) 3))
 )
```

Edit: Can't respond to your comment, but the following doesn't work:

```
(setq cc-imenu-c++-generic-expression ((nil "^\\<
```

That's because the `((` is not quoted. (Emacs) Lisp sees a bare `(` as the command to call a function. You need to use ` or `'` to quote it. So `((` says call the function returned by calling `nil ...`

Comment: Have you observed a wide array of false positives with this change?  I see imenu entries representing single keywords like if. It matches something like `if (condition)` as a function.

Comment: No, I didn't test it on large files. But yeah, matching things like `if (condition)` is probably why the had the no-whitespace-in-beginning-of-line rule :(

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate. imenu is often useless at my work due to the namespaces used.

Comment: Have you tried using semantic instead?

Comment: I have not. The code base is fairly large, and I have been scared off by warnings of slowness in semantic and cedet. But you are right, this should be my next step.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this exact same problem.  I took the same approach as @omajid and modified a copy of the cc-imenu-c++-generic-expression variable.  I found that the false matches were caused by the second regex with the `Special case to match a line like "main() {}"` comment.  My approach was to modify the regular expressions apart from that special case one to add an optional 4 spaces at the start of the line.  I added another regular expression similar to the special case one to match constructors and destructors which the special case expression would otherwise have matched apart from the indentation.

This is the code I added to my init.el file:

```
(require 'cc-mode)

;; modify the regex variable that cc-mode uses to cope with finding function definitions inside namespaces
(setq cc-imenu-c++-generic-expression
  `(
    ;; Try to match ::operator definitions first. Otherwise `X::operator new ()'
    ;; will be incorrectly recognized as function `new ()' because the regexps
    ;; work by backtracking from the end of the definition.
    (nil
     ,(concat
       "^\\<.*"                               ; 
       "[^" c-alnum "_:<>~]"                  ; match any non-identifier char
                                              ; (note: this can be `\n')
       "\\("
      "\\([" c-alnum "_:<>~]*::\\)?"      ; match an operator
          "operator\\>[ \t]*"
          "\\(()\\|[^(]*\\)"                  ; special case for `()' operator
       "\\)"

       "[ \t]*([^)]*)[ \t]*[^ \t;]"           ; followed by ws, arg list,
                                              ; require something other than
                                              ; a `;' after the (...) to
                                              ; avoid prototypes.  Can't
                                              ; catch cases with () inside
                                              ; the parentheses surrounding
                                              ; the parameters.  e.g.:
                                              ; `int foo(int a=bar()) {...}'
       ) 1)
    ;; Special case to match a line like "main() {}"
    ;; e.g. no return type, not even on the previous line.
    (nil
     ,(concat
       "^"                       ; beginning of line
       "\\([" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_:<>~]*\\)" ; match function name
       "[ \t]*("                  ; see above, BUT
       "[ \t]*\\([^ \t(*][^)]*\\)?)"          ; the arg list must not start
       "[ \t]*[^ \t;(]"                       ; with an asterisk or parentheses
       ) 1)
    ;; constructor or destructor functions
    (nil
     ,(concat
       "^\\(?:    \\)?"                       ; beginning of line after an optional 4 spaces
       "\\([" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_]*::~?[" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_<>]*\\)"  ; match constructor/destructor function name
       "[ \t]*("                  ; see above, BUT
       "[ \t]*\\([^ \t(*][^)]*\\)?)"          ; the arg list must not start
       "[ \t]*[^ \t;(]"                       ; with an asterisk or parentheses
       ) 1)
    ;; General function name regexp
    (nil
     ,(concat
       "^\\(?:    \\)?\\<[^#]"                ; line MUST start with word char after an optional 4 spaces (but not lines starting with a # character)
       ;; \n added to prevent overflow in regexp matcher.
       ;; https://lists.gnu.org/r/emacs-pretest-bug/2007-02/msg00021.html
       "[^()/\n]*"                            ; no parentheses or forward slash before
       "[^" c-alnum "_:<>~]"                  ; match any non-identifier char
       "\\([" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_:<>~]*\\)" ; match function name
       "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*("         ; see above, BUT the arg list
       "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*"          ; must not start
       "\\([^ \t\n(*]"                ; with an asterisk or parentheses
       "[^()]*\\(([^()]*)[^()]*\\)*"          ; Maybe function pointer arguments
       "\\)?)"
       "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*[^ \t\n;(]"
       ) 1)
    ;; Special case for definitions using phony prototype macros like:
    ;; `int main _PROTO( (int argc,char *argv[]) )'.
    ;; This case is only included if cc-imenu-c-prototype-macro-regexp is set.
    ;; Only supported in c-code, so no `:<>~' chars in function name!
    ,@(if cc-imenu-c-prototype-macro-regexp
            `((nil
                 ,(concat
                   "^\\<.*"                   ; line MUST start with word char
           "[^" c-alnum "_]"          ; match any non-identifier char
           "\\([" c-alpha "_][" c-alnum "_]*\\)" ; match function name
                   "[ \t]*"                   ; whitespace before macro name
                   cc-imenu-c-prototype-macro-regexp
                   "[ \t]*("                  ; ws followed by first paren.
                   "[ \t]*([^)]*)[ \t]*)[ \t]*[^ \t;]" ; see above
                   ) 1)))
    ;; Class definitions
    ("Class"
     ,(concat
         "^\\(?:    \\)?"                     ; beginning of line is required after an optional 4 spaces
         "\\(template[ \t]*<[^>]+>[ \t]*\\)?" ; there may be a `template <...>'
         "\\(class\\|struct\\)[ \t]+"
         "\\("                                ; the string we want to get
     "[" c-alnum "_]+"                    ; class name
         "\\(<[^>]+>\\)?"                     ; possibly explicitly specialized
         "\\)"
         "\\([ \t\n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*[:{]"
         ) 3)))
```

I used an optional 4 spaces rather than an arbitrary amount of whitespace characters to minimise any false positives. Using an optional 4 spaces allows for normal non-indented functions not inside a namespace and for functions defined inside a namespace. I am using the newer C++ standard which allows for nested namespaces like so:

```
namespace My::Nested::Namespace {
    void foo() {}
}
```

so all my functions are either indented by 4 spaces or not indented at all.